# Apache and mod_rewrite: Point any domain to any directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been working with my `.htaccess` file and mod_rewrite for a couple of days now trying to create a rule that allows people to point their own domains to paths of my website.

i.e. they have created a landing page on my website, located at `www.website.com/landingPages/myUniqueWebsite`
and they would like to point their domain, `www.myuniquewebsite.com` to that url above.

Could anyone suggest what apache rule to use to accomplish this? 
My `.htaccess` currently looks like this:

```
# disallow access to any directories without an index file
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on
# remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /myProject/$1 [L,R=301]

FallbackResource ../appContent/BasePage.php
```

Where the `BasePage` above takes the directory data from the URL and gets the users landing page data from the db.

Also should they be using domain pointing or aliasing in their hosting provider dashboard?

Comment: You should use virtual hosts of apache for that.

Comment: Take a look into RewriteMap directive. It allows you to specify your own script to associate between subdomain and user's directory. 

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap